# WebView Not Loading a Specific Webpage

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, webview

For a little context, I am currently working on an irc client based off of the open source kiwiirc web app. I'm building it to be cross platform so I have been doing some preliminary testing just to simply load the kiwiirc.com client in a web view.

Nothing fancy, just load the page up in a webview, and log in to an IRC server. On iOS using the standard UIKit frameworks, and for Desktop using Qt I have had great success.

On android not so much...

For some reason unbeknownst to me the webview on Android refuses to load the content for the address https://kiwiirc.com/client

It will load https://kiwiirc.com/ just fine, and in fact it will load any other website just fine as well. The only URL I have an issue with is the core one I need access to.

I've been trying to solve this problem for a few days now, and figured I'd come to the stack overflow community for some help since I am out of ideas.

The following is my code that I am currently using:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);


    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });


    webView.loadUrl("https://kiwiirc.com/client");


 }
}
```

Here are the following things I have tried in the order I have tried them, as well as their results, while I have been troubleshooting this issue:

1. Enabling Javascript - no affect on loading the webpage
2. Enabling DomStorage - no affect on loading the webpage
3. Embedding KiwiIRC in iFrame on another webpage - will load the webpage and kiwi embed PERFECTLY, but unfortunately I cannot fetch data from the iframe due to the "Same Origin" security policy.

*EDIT*

Relevant note: https://kiwiirc.com/client loads correctly via the android google chrome browser, but not in the webview of my app.

If anyone can offer me tips on troubleshooting this issue, provide me with a solution, or point out some obviously trivial thing I forgot to do, that would be amazing.

Thanks!